# Unable to play video in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I am working on ubuntu 14.04 with Qt 5.8 and trying to play video in my application using Qt multimedia module. I put "QT += quick multimedia" in ".pro".

**ContentVideo.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtMultimedia 5.0

Rectangle {
    width: 400
    height: 400
    color:"black"

    MediaPlayer {
        id: mediaPlayer
        autoPlay: true
        autoLoad: true
        source:"/home/macos/Desktop/FroggerHighway.mp4"
    }

    VideoOutput {
        id:videoOutput
        source:mediaPlayer
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.1

Window {
    id: root
    color: "black"
    width: 400
    height: 400
    visible: true
    ContentVideo {
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

My video is not running and I am getting black screen without any error. QT QML EXAMPLES video is working on my PC. Any help will appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

MediaPlayer.source is a URI and I don't think the value you are specifying is a valid URI. Try adding "file://" in front of the path the the mp4 file.

Comment: THANK'S A LOT FOR YOU 'RE RESPONSE

Answer (score 2):

I had just met the same issue as yours, it seems that QtMultimedia will looking for decoders from gstreamer in system at run time, so I install video codec package:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-vaapi
```

Then qml video player works correctly now

Answer (score 1):

If the QML video examples work without any issues it's probably a problem that comes from the lack of codecs to encode your video. Check if you have all the [Multimedia Dependencies](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-requirements.html). My guess is that the provided video samples are encoded in a open format the support for which is provided by default by your distro.

Answer (score 1):

Add  `QT+= multimedia` to your `.pro` file.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem on Arch and Debian. After installing the following packages, everything works fine.

**ARCH:**

- extra/gstreamer
- aur/gstreamer0.10
- extra/gst-plugins-base-libs
- extra/gst-plugins-good
- extra/gst-libav
- extra/qt5-tools

Installed with `yay`:

```
yay -S gstreamer gstreamer0.10 gst-plugins-base-libs gst-plugins-good gst-libav qt5-tools
```

**Debian:**

- libqt5multimedia5-plugins
- gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
- gstreamer1.0-libav
- libqt5multimediagsttools5

Installed with `apt`:

```
apt install libqt5multimedia5-plugins
```

Answer (score 0):

Since qt6 prefers cmake instead of qmake so in case you want to add multimedia files to your cmake list you could perfrom the steps given below (the solution below worked on a mac (apple silicon))

1. First download the multimedia package from the  qt maintenance tool (QtMultimedia) [image]

2. Add it to the cmake project list by including the following lines

   ```
    find_package(Qt6 6.2 COMPONENTS Multimedia REQUIRED)
   ```
3. Also update the target_link_libraries

   ```
    target_link_libraries(yourprojectname, PRIVATE Qt6::Multimedia)
   ```
4. Also set autorcc on

   ```
    set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
   ```
5. Save your cmake file
6. Regarding the qml file the following code worked for me without errors

   ```
    import QtQuick
    import QtQuick.Controls
    import QtMultimedia

    ApplicationWindow
    {
        width:640
        height: 480
        visible : true
        title: "audio player"
        MediaPlayer {
            id: player 
            source : "give your path to source file "
            audioOutput: AudioOutput{}

        Component.onCompleted:{
            player.play();
        }
       }
      }
   ```